# MySQL: SUM(CASE WHEN(...)) + GROUP BY. Why details of dataset cannot show even with GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, case-when

*Credit: Leetcode 1308. Running Total for Different Genders*

Sample Score table:

```
+-------------+--------+------------+--------------+
| player_name | gender | day        | score_points |
+-------------+--------+------------+--------------+
| Aron        | F      | 2020-01-01 | 17           |
| Alice       | F      | 2020-01-07 | 23           |
| Bajrang     | M      | 2020-01-07 | 7            |
| Khali       | M      | 2019-12-25 | 11           |
| Slaman      | M      | 2019-12-30 | 13           |
| Joe         | M      | 2019-12-31 | 3            |
| Jose        | M      | 2019-12-18 | 2            |
| Priya       | F      | 2019-12-31 | 23           |
| Priyanka    | F      | 2019-12-30 | 17           |
+-------------+--------+------------+--------------+
```

Requirement: Write an SQL query to find the (cumulative) total score for each gender at each day.
Order the result table by gender and day. The sample Result table is as follows:

```
+--------+------------+-------+
| gender | day        | total |
+--------+------------+-------+
| F      | 2019-12-30 | 17    |
| F      | 2019-12-31 | 40    |
| F      | 2020-01-01 | 57    |
| F      | 2020-01-07 | 80    |
| M      | 2019-12-18 | 2     |
| M      | 2019-12-25 | 13    |
| M      | 2019-12-30 | 26    |
| M      | 2019-12-31 | 29    |
| M      | 2020-01-07 | 36    |
+--------+------------+-------+
```

My code is as follows. I cannot figure out why it only returns one row[{"headers": ["gender", "day", "total"], "values": [["F", "2019-12-30", 184]]}], even with GROUP BY.

```
SELECT s1.gender, s1.day, 
SUM(CASE WHEN s1.day < s2.day AND s1.gender = s2.gender THEN s1.score_points ELSE 0 END) AS total
FROM Scores s1, Scores s2
GROUP BY s1.gender AND s1.day
ORDER BY s1.gender AND s1.day
```

Thank you so much if anyone can help me out!!

Comment: Specify MySQL version.

Comment: *Requirement: Write an SQL query to find the total score for each gender at each day. ... The sample Result table is as follows:* Shown result is cumulative sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do a proper join with an `ON` clause and use valid syntax for `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`:

```
select s1.gender, s1.day, sum(s2.score_points) total
from scores s1 inner join scores s2
on s2.gender = s1.gender and s2.day <= s1.day
group by s1.gender, s1.day
order by s1.gender, s1.day
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6X9HieSiMw4T3e7grzo5JJ/0).
Results:

```
| gender | day        | total |
| ------ | -----------| ----- |
| F      | 2019-12-30 | 17    |
| F      | 2019-12-31 | 40    |
| F      | 2020-01-01 | 57    |
| F      | 2020-01-07 | 80    |
| M      | 2019-12-18 | 2     |
| M      | 2019-12-25 | 13    |
| M      | 2019-12-30 | 26    |
| M      | 2019-12-31 | 29    |
| M      | 2020-01-07 | 36    |
```

Answer (score 0):

`AND` is a boolean operation that returns true/false (1/0).  You seem to want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT s.day, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.gender = 'M' THEN s.score_points ELSE 0 END) AS total_male,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.gender = 'F' THEN s.score_points ELSE 0 END) AS total_female
FROM Scores s
GROUP BY s.day
ORDER BY s.day;
```

The `GROUP BY` keys determine what the result set looks like.  Each set of unique values has one row in the result set, with the rest of the columns summarized to fit on the row.

In this case, you want one row per day, so that is what should be in the `GROUP BY`.

Then for the cumulative amount use window funtions:

```
SELECT s.day, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.gender = 'M' THEN s.score_points ELSE 0 END) AS total_male,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.gender = 'F' THEN s.score_points ELSE 0 END) AS total_female,
       SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN s.gender = 'M' THEN s.score_points ELSE 0 END)) OVER (ORDER BY s.day) AS running_male,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.gender = 'F' THEN s.score_points ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY s.day) AS running_female
FROM Scores s
GROUP BY s.day
ORDER BY s.day;
```

Comment: I see the problem of me using group by. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would be efficient, but it'll pass through:

```
SELECT T1.gender, T1.day, SUM(T2.score_points) AS total
FROM Scores T1
JOIN Scores T2
WHERE T1.gender = T2.gender AND T2.day <= T1.day
GROUP BY T1.gender, t1.day
ORDER BY t1.gender, t1.day;
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/running-total-for-different-genders/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.

Comment: Thank u for the suggestion! I did saw many great answers there but wanted to know why I was wrong. Now it's all solved. Thanks!